# How do you find the base url from a DLL in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, url, web-applications

From within a DLL that's being called by a C#.NET web app, how do you find the base url of the web app?

Comment: Can you post an example of the full URL and what you want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Will this work?

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

UPDATE:

To get the base URL you can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped)
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander - I worked out something using that part of HttpContext.

Comment: You saved my time!!

Answer (score 1):

If it's an assembly that might be referenced by non-web projects then you might want to avoid using the System.Web namespace.

I would use DannySmurf's method.

Answer (score 1):

As Alexander says, you can use HttpContext.Current.Request.Url  but if you doesn't want to use the http://:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.HostAndPort, UriFormat.Unescaped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() to get the assembly object for the DLL.

Then, call Server.MapPath, passing in the FullPath of that Assembly to get the local, rooted path.

Comment: I'm looking for the URL of the site not the directory path. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this although I'm not sure if it's the best solution:

```
string _baseUrl = String.Empty;
HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
if (httpContext != null)
{
    _baseURL = "http://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.IsDefaultPort)
    {
        _baseURL += ":" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port;
    }
}
```